# Out of Bounds of an Array [Bubble Selection with ArrayList]

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm coding a Bubble Selection method, which should work with these credentials:

```
/* Write code for a Bubble Sort algorithm that starts at the right side of
 * of ArrayList of Comparable objects and "bubbles" the largest item to the
 * left of the list.  The result should be an ArrayList arranged in descending
 * order.
 */
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
 void bubbleSort(ArrayList <Comparable> list) {

    int end = list.size();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < end; i++){
        for (int j = end; j > 0; j--){
            if ( list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(j-1)) > 0 ){
                //swap
                Comparable temp = list.get(j);
                list.set(j,list.get(j - 1));
                list.set(j - 1, temp);
                //System.out.println(list);
            }
        }   
        end--;
    }
}
```

The problem is, Java will then tell me it is out of bounds.

If I instead use

```
for (int j = end - 1; j > 0; j--)
```

the code will then run, however it does not run the number of times it needs to run for the list to completely finish sorting (aka it stops one loop ahead)

Comment: In the inner loop you have N objects and you want to compare each one with the previous to swap them if needed, so you have to do N-1 checks since the first does not have a previous one. `for (int j = end - 1; j > 0; j--)` is right.

Answer (score 1):

As explained, you need to start in end-1, or else you'll be accessing out of bounds of the array.

---

Let's say you have an array of integers: `5 1 4`

Your algorith will do this:

1st iteration -> i = 0 / j starting at 2

```
1 5 4
```

2nd iteration -> i = 1 / j starting at 1

It will now only compare 5 and 1 and not switching them, because 5 is higher. So, and the 4 and 5? They should be swapped. Your algorithm implementation is wrong.

If you remove the  `end--;` it should work. 
However, this can be optimized

Comment: You're right, you're using j-1, so it will try to search on the index -1. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will work for your requirement in array implementation where **size** is your array length.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; j++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size - 1; k++){
        if (array[i] > array[j]) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp; 
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is long 3, array[3] is out of bound.
Since you start with array[lenght] you have to decrement it before entering in the for cycle like the code you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Using `end - 1` will compare last and second last values in list
if you use `end` it will try to compare last value and value at index after last which will give `ArrayOutOfBound Exception`.

Now For correct output you have to remove `end--;` line as per shown below

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < end; i++){
        for (int j = end -1; j > 0; j--){
            if ( list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(j-1)) > 0 ){
                //swap
                Comparable temp = list.get(j);
                list.set(j,list.get(j - 1));
                list.set(j - 1, temp);
            }
        } 
        //remove below line
        end--;
    }
```

This will short the list by one value from right side also. So removing This will work